# Reload store / refresh grid in main window when button is clicked in Modal window in EXTJS

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I am facing a problem in my EXTJS application.

Basically there is a grid which displays all the projects. In my main menu which is a different file, I have "Add Project" link. On clicking this, Add Project modal window opens irrespective of any main window which may be project list or dashboard currently displaying in browser.

Now I want if the main page is the Project List in the browser and I open the Add Project modal, When I will click Add button, I want the grid / store in the project list page should reload or refresh.

I am not getting any way to get a reference to the project store in the project list page from the Add Project modal window.

Can any one please help me on this.

Thanks in Advance... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Ext.getStore('your_store_name');` to get a reference to your store.

The sencha grid tutorial covers this: http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/grid